# my php code. on lws cannot be interpreted

Tags: php

I have a big concern which is: I have developed a web application which already works on another server for more than several months. but when I migrate my application to an LWS server the php code does not get ready.
for example if my code is `<? php echo 'Hello';` even on the web the same code instead of: Hello

Comment: Try using `<?php` instead of short tags `<?`. Short tags have been disabled as default in PHP since a bunch of versions back. If it's too cumbersome to change them, you can try and change your php.ini to allow short tags. But a simple search and replace in the code should sort that out.

Comment: 1. Sounds like the web server in the new environment isn't configured to run PHP. Do you have admin access? 2. This isn't really a programming question; Server Fault or Super User may be a better place to ask this